# Wordpress Custom Meta Box

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom meta box which displays only on the home page when I go in to edit the page.

This is all working great, but I want to carry the text entered on the home page custom meta box on every page.

I currently have the following code that outputs the text:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_meta_box_text_challengetbl', true); ?>
```

The question is how do I get the custom meta box text entered on the home page for every page?

Comment: Get the home page ID from the URL in the admin section when editing the page, then replace that with get_the_ID. So get_post_meta(73,  'my_meta_box_text_challengetbl', true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

$homePageId = get_option('page_on_front');

echo get_post_meta($homePageId, 'my_meta_box_text_challengetbl', true);
?>
```

[Here's a list of many useful get_option parameters.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference)

Comment: I feel happy to help you.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of the answer posted 13 hours earlier. How does this answer add to the discussion?

Comment: @rnevius if you feel this is an duplicate question then raise flag,  it seems you also answering on same question.

Comment: It's a duplicate answer; not a duplicate question.

Comment: that does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a static front page, you can get the ID of the front page by using `get_option()`, and then retrieve the post meta using that ID:

```
$front_page_ID = get_option('page_on_front');
echo get_post_meta($front_page_ID, 'my_meta_box_text_challengetbl', true);
```

Read more about options [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference#Reading).